# how do I test a service in isolation when it depends on other modules?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

How do I test my `$myService`?

The `$myService` depends on another service `$foo`. Service `$foo` is in a different module.

```
// a service.
angular.module("plunker").factory('$foo', function () {
    return {
        bar: function (msg) {
            //do something here.
        }
    };
});

// a service that depends on the other service.
angular.module("app").factory('$myService', function ($foo) {
    return {
        test: function (msg) {
            $foo.bar(msg);
        }
    };
});
```

This test is giving me an error:

```
describe('testing some service', function (){
  var svc,
      mockFooSvc;

  beforeEach(function (){
    module('app', function($provide) {

      mockFooSvc = {
        bar: function (){}
      };

      spyOn(mockFooSvc, 'bar');

      $provide.value('$foo', mockFooSvc);
    });

    //now we inject the service we're testing.
    inject(function($myService) {
      svc = $myService;
    });
  });

  it('should call $foo.bar on $myService.test passing through parameters.', function (){
    //make the call.
    svc.test('WEE!');

    //check our spy to see if bar was called properly.
    expect(mockFooSvc.bar).toHaveBeenCalledWith('WEE!');
  });
});
```

The error:

```
x Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module plunker due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'plunker' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/$injector/nomod?p0=plunker
```

In my app.JS I've already added plunker as a dependency.

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngCookies", "ngResource", "ngRoute", "tyNav", "http-auth-interceptor", "plunker"]);
```

Comment: It's only a guess but did you try returning null from module('app', function($provide) { ... return null; }?

Comment: Why would that be necessary? If the `$foo` service was in the `app` module, then the test is green.

Comment: module('app', function($provide) { ... } has no $foo service. change it to plunker and load the app module too.

Comment: Could you plese post your app module dependencies? angular.module("app", [...])

Comment: I've added it, I'm not sure what you mean by your previous comment, would you mind posting an answer with more code?

Comment: What about the plunker module. how do you define the module?

Comment: @bekite right there in the first line - `angular.module("plunker").factory('$foo', function () {`

Comment: yes that's the problem: angular.module("plunker") doesn't define a module you need to define it using: angular.module('plunker', []). This explains the strange error you get.